# React - how to capture only parent's onClick event and not children

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I have part of a React Component that looks like this:

```
var headerElement = someBoolean ? <input/> : 'some string';
return <th onClick={this._onHeaderClick}>{headerElement}</th>;
```

And a click handler for the `th` element:

```
_onHeaderClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target);
},
```

I want to capture the `th` element. It works fine when `headerElement` is 'some string', but when it is an `input` element, the `input` element is the one referenced in the `event.target` property.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Since you are binding the handler to `th` you can use the [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property. The [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property refers to the element which dispatched the event.

```
_onHeaderClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
}
```

Answer (score 53):

Check them

```
_onHeaderClick(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if(event.target === event.currentTarget) {
      // handle
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this?

```
event.target.parentNode
```

Comment: That looks a little cumbersome. I would have to make validations first.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason the accepted solution did not work for me.

One possible work-around is to add a `data-value` tag to the child element you wish to exclude from the `onClick` event:

```
const eg = () => {

    const clickParent = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {

        event.preventDefault();
        let dataValue = (event.target as HTMLElement).getAttribute('data-value');
        if (dataValue !== 'child') {
            console.log('parent clicked');
        };

    };

    const clickChild = (event: React.MouseEvent) => console.log('child clicked');

    return (

        <div data-value='parent' onClick={clickParent}>

            <div data-value='child' onClick={clickChild}>
            </div>

        </div>

    );


};
```

Answer (score 2):

simply use [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

```
 onClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
}
```