# Return the parent div onClick with React

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I have a list of div's with a click event that I would like to return the parent element, `parent-1` or `parent-2` in this example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-https-mc774

`e.target` is giving me the exact element that was clicked.  It is possible I might have further nested elements, so I need to find a way to get back to `parent-1` or `parent-2`

Comment: You want to use `e.target.parentNode` if the clicked `div` is the immediate child of parent div. You could also use `closest()` method `e.target.closest('.parent')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this post which is exactly what I was needing to accomplish

[React - how to capture only parent's onClick event and not children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349136/react-how-to-capture-only-parents-onclick-event-and-not-children)